# Download a pdf from a website every 24 hours?

Tags: windows-7, script, file-download

I recently found G24, a pdf that The Guardian updates regularly with news summaries, which I can then print out.

Is there a method to download said pdf every 24 hours? It has a static link, as they simply update the pdf, and is readily accessible (no login required).

link: http://download.guardian.co.uk/g24/World.pdf

Comment: your OS? Windows? win7? ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$source = "http://download.guardian.co.uk/g24/World.pdf"
$dest = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\World.pdf"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

Powershell script above , and then use the [Task Scheduler](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx) to Run a Windows PowerShell Script.

To add a datestamp to the file, change the $dest variable:

```
$dest = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\World $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).pdf"
```

Filename = "World 2012-12-15.pdf".

This date will be the date of the scheduled date execution. If the file is not updated, you will get the same pdf with a different date stamp.

Comment: If I wanted to append a date to the pdf to keep them separate how would I do so?

Comment: added the date stamp to answer...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to add a cron job to run every 24 hours.

`http://download.guardian.co.uk/g24/World.pdf` to download it.
And `crontab -e` to edit your cron schedule.

Comment: I'll upvote this for *nix users. I'm on Windoze7

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to create a "recipe" on https://ifttt.com that will grab the pdf and then automatically upload it to your google drive for example.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Have you tested this website and can you confirm it will work in a way required by the OP. Thanks.